# simple htaccess RewriteRule is not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

hello I have urls in this format : http://domain.com/index.php?action=page&name=privacy
would like to use domain.com/page/privacy instead of http://domain.com/index.php?action=page&name=privacy using htaccess. any ideas please

```
RewriteRule \/index\.php\/(.*)$ /action/$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Not Found The requested URL /page/privacy was not found on this server.I did check that rewrite module is active. any thoughts ?

Comment: I had to do Allowoverride All in httpd.conf for htaccess. Now works great thanks anubhava